# Is my webcam stream invisible because of codec?

Tags: javascript, html, codec, getusermedia, vp8

I've to disp on a webpage the user webcam. I've a "working" html page, as it do not give errors. unfortunately, the video of the camera is invisible. It's here, as I see with elements inspection tool (F12) : it highlight a rectangle where the video should be, but there is nothing visible.
Here is the code :

```html
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body">
        <main>
            <video style="background-color: blue;" id="playback" width="60%" height="60%"></video>
            <script>
                const constraints = {
                    video: {
                    width: {
                        min: 1280,
                        ideal: 1920,
                        max: 2560,
                    },
                    height: {
                        min: 720,
                        ideal: 1080,
                        max: 1440
                    },
                    }
                };

                if ('mediaDevices' in navigator && 'getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices) {
                    console.log("OK getUserMedia")
                }
                else(console.log("!OK getUserMedia"))

                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                .then(function(stream){
                    console.log("cam on");
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                        video = document.getElementById("playback");
                        video.srcObject = stream;
                    } )
                })
                .catch (function(error) {
                console.log("error camera acces", e);
                })
            </script>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

how annoying ! So I tried checking browser updates, another browser, another computer, another wifi connexion (hopeless I am, yesss), adding key words as `autoplay` `muted` `playsinline` or `controls`, forcing css `visibility` tag at `visible`... nothing helps.
So one step back, two forwards. I decided to forgot cam for a while, and using a local video : same issue, it's invisible (good name, good path...). Then i saw on forums some people talking 'bout codec ! I downloaded a mp4 the codec of the stream is the issue ? according to this [page](https://www.onsip.com/voip-resources/voip-fundamentals/getusermedia), `getUserMedia` send a stream with VP8 codec, [which is supposed to supported by all browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=vp8), so it's unlikely but eh ! at this state, I can try everything. :(
In your opinion, is the codec the issue ? can I change it ? May you think to other ways I can explore ?
---EDIT---
Naivly I tried to add`codec: 'h264'` to constraints but eheh no. x)

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using `DOMContentLoaded` incorrectly here: if `getUserMedia`'s Promise resolves after `DOMContentLoaded` then the `video.srcObject = stream;` statement will never run.

Comment: `.catch (function(error) {` <-- Your parameter is named `error` but you're passing `e` to `console.log`, which is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for returns. Not the solution, but corrections made and kept for a more rigorous code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The problem is your call to `getUserMedia` returns a `Promise<>` that resolves *after* the `DOMContentLoaded` event...

  - ...which means the `video.srcObject = stream;` statement will never be evaluated.
- Additionally, there's a few other things wrong with your existing code:

  - You need to `return` or `throw` if `getUserMedia` is unavailable, but your code has a single inline `else` branch with no `return`.
  - Your code in `.catch (function(error) { console.log("error camera acces", e); } )` is incorrect: there is no variable named `e`: it's `error`.
- Instead, `await` the `getUserMedia` Promise *after* `DOMContentLoaded`, like so:

```js
const constraints = {
  video: {
    width: {
      min: 1280,
      ideal: 1920,
      max: 2560,
    },
    height: {
      min: 720,
      ideal: 1080,
      max: 1440
    },
  }
};

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', setup );

async function setup() {

  if( !'mediaDevices' in navigator ) return;
  if( !'getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices ) return;
  
  const videoEl = document.getElementById("playback");
  if( !videoEl ) return;
  
  //
  
  let stream;
  try {
      stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  }
  catch( err ) {

    // Consider handling only the specific exceptions listed on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#exceptions

    console.error( "Error: %o", err );
    alert( "navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia failed: " + err );
    return;
  }
  
  videoEl.srcObject = stream;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <video style="background-color: blue;" id="playback" width="60%" height="60%"></video>
</main>
```

Comment: @Tsu'Na What browser are you using? I don't get any errors in Chrome 113.

Comment: Hello, many thnaks for code !
Unfortunately, with the 2 returns, i got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement" in the console. So I handlet it with throw and try/catch (cant bloc code in comments :( )
About the async function, well it was the first version of my page, and I had this issue. It appears that `.then` statement was the way to wait for the promise to be resolved... I'm trying to change my DOMContentLoader position, as you made, then I come back in new comment (out of characters...)

Comment: You can't use `try/catch` for Syntax Errors.... Please post a link to a page that demonstrates the problem you're experiencing because I can't reproduce it at my end.

Comment: I tried on chrome, Edge, Firefox, both updated. I did same on Linux and Windows. :(

Comment: well it's not online : I'm trying by just opening html page in chrome with script in the html page, or then launching a live server ("live server" extension in Visual Studio Code)

Comment: Is there any service I can use to put my html on a server for free (I can't afford a web hoster as one.com or others)